# Reading Multiple levels of repeated JSON structure data in Google BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, unnest, json-extract

I am trying to read the below JSON structure. Was able to get the data to 1 level and see its reading Correctly, but when I go deeper into the other sections.its not reading data correctly. Below is the Input data and the Code Iam using and Output for your perusal. Request your help with this.

- **INPUT DATA:**

  {
  "ProjectId": "P.2000002",
  "OperationId": "O.2000002.01",
  "ActivityId": "A.2000002.01.01",
  "Description": "",
  "Combos": [
    {
      "ComboId": "9146",
      "Demands": {
        "DownHoleTools": {
          "PrimaryTools": [
            {
              "ToolCode": "19139",
              "ToolDescription": "VSIT-C/D",
              "IsEdoApplicable": true,
              "Source": "A",
              "DemandDurationInfo": {
                "StartDate": "2019-09-09T17:42:10",
                "EndDate": "2019-09-19T23:00:00"
              },
              "HashNumber": 1,
              "ClassificationName": "VSIT-C/D",
              "ClassificationType": 0,
              "GroupInfo": {
                "Code": "1519",
                "Description": "VSIT"
              },
              "CategoryInfo": {
                "Code": "1519",
                "Description": "VSIT"
              },
              "Comments": "",
              "IsDeleted": false,
              "PartNumber": "",
              "Description": "",
              "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "CreatedBy": "",
              "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "LastModifiedBy": "",
              "Id": "1"
            },
            {
              "ToolCode": "7030",
              "ToolDescription": "VSIB-P",
              "IsEdoApplicable": false,
              "Source": "A",
              "DemandDurationInfo": {
                "StartDate": "2019-09-09T17:42:12",
                "EndDate": "2019-09-19T23:00:00"
              },
              "HashNumber": 1,
              "ClassificationName": "VSIB-P",
              "ClassificationType": 0,
              "GroupInfo": {
                "Code": "1519",
                "Description": "VSIT"
              },
              "CategoryInfo": {
                "Code": "1519",
                "Description": "VSIT"
              },
              "Comments": "",
              "IsDeleted": false,
              "PartNumber": "",
              "Description": "",
              "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "CreatedBy": "",
              "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "LastModifiedBy": "",
              "Id": "1"
            },
            {
              "ToolCode": "3707",
              "ToolDescription": "HILT-TLD-H",
              "IsEdoApplicable": false,
              "Source": "A",
              "DemandDurationInfo": {
                "StartDate": "2020-02-12T15:18:32",
                "EndDate": "2020-02-13T15:18:32"
              },
              "HashNumber": 1,
              "ClassificationName": "HILT-TLD-H",
              "ClassificationType": 0,
              "GroupInfo": {
                "Code": "842",
                "Description": "HILT"
              },
              "CategoryInfo": {
                "Code": "842",
                "Description": "HILT"
              },
              "Comments": "",
              "IsDeleted": false,
              "PartNumber": "",
              "Description": "HILT-TLD-H",
              "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "CreatedBy": "",
              "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "LastModifiedBy": "",
              "Id": "1"
            },
            {
              "ToolCode": "3707",
              "ToolDescription": "HILT-TLD-H",
              "IsEdoApplicable": false,
              "Source": "A",
              "DemandDurationInfo": {
                "StartDate": "2020-02-12T15:18:32",
                "EndDate": "2020-02-13T15:18:32"
              },
              "HashNumber": 2,
              "ClassificationName": "HILT-TLD-H",
              "ClassificationType": 0,
              "GroupInfo": {
                "Code": "842",
                "Description": "HILT"
              },
              "CategoryInfo": {
                "Code": "842",
                "Description": "HILT"
              },
              "Comments": "",
              "IsDeleted": false,
              "PartNumber": "",
              "Description": "HILT-TLD-H",
              "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "CreatedBy": "",
              "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "LastModifiedBy": "",
              "Id": "1"
            }
          ],
          "BackupTools": [

  ```
      ]
    },
    "SurfaceTools": {
      "PrimaryTools": [
        {
          "ToolCode": "19153",
          "ToolDescription": "MDT_Surface Eqpt",
          "IsEdoApplicable": false,
          "Source": "A",
          "DemandDurationInfo": {
            "StartDate": "2020-02-12T15:18:32",
            "EndDate": "2020-02-13T15:18:32"
          },
          "HashNumber": 1,
          "ClassificationName": "MDT_Surface Eqpt",
          "ClassificationType": 1,
          "GroupInfo": {
            "Code": "965",
            "Description": "MDT Accessories"
          },
          "CategoryInfo": {
            "Code": "965",
            "Description": "MDT Accessories"
          },
          "Comments": "",
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "PartNumber": "",
          "Description": "MDT_Surface Eqpt",
          "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "CreatedBy": "",
          "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "LastModifiedBy": "",
          "Id": "1"
        },
        {
          "ToolCode": "19153",
          "ToolDescription": "MDT_Surface Eqpt",
          "IsEdoApplicable": false,
          "Source": "A",
          "DemandDurationInfo": {
            "StartDate": "2020-02-12T15:18:32",
            "EndDate": "2020-02-13T15:18:32"
          },
          "HashNumber": 2,
          "ClassificationName": "MDT_Surface Eqpt",
          "ClassificationType": 1,
          "GroupInfo": {
            "Code": "965",
            "Description": "MDT Accessories"
          },
          "CategoryInfo": {
            "Code": "965",
            "Description": "MDT Accessories"
          },
          "Comments": "",
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "PartNumber": "",
          "Description": "MDT_Surface Eqpt",
          "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "CreatedBy": "",
          "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "LastModifiedBy": "",
          "Id": "1"
        }
      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Techniques": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Services": [

    ],
    "Tools": ""
  },
  "ComboType": 2,
  "HashCode": "",
  "SequenceNumber": "",
  "ConveyanceInfo": "",
  "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "CreatedBy": "",
  "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "LastModifiedBy": "",
  "Id": "98e9418f-e50a-417b-affb-5fc4c1f71f39"
  ```

  },
    {
      "ComboId": "5970",
      "Demands": {
        "DownHoleTools": {
          "PrimaryTools": [

  ```
      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "SurfaceTools": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Techniques": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Services": [

    ],
    "Tools": ""
  },
  "ComboType": 1,
  "HashCode": "",
  "SequenceNumber": "",
  "ConveyanceInfo": "",
  "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "CreatedBy": "",
  "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "LastModifiedBy": "",
  "Id": "944cf025-2a8c-4372-9f87-6c80c844ac68"
  ```

  },
    {
      "ComboId": "5971",
      "Demands": {
        "DownHoleTools": {
          "PrimaryTools": [

  ```
      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "SurfaceTools": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Techniques": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Services": [

    ],
    "Tools": ""
  },
  "ComboType": 0,
  "HashCode": "",
  "SequenceNumber": "",
  "ConveyanceInfo": "",
  "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "CreatedBy": "",
  "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "LastModifiedBy": "",
  "Id": "0a9338b2-aa95-4d5a-8e57-1305e78fec0c"
  ```

  },
    {
      "ComboId": "26793",
      "Demands": {
        "DownHoleTools": {
          "PrimaryTools": [

  ```
      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "SurfaceTools": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Techniques": {
      "PrimaryTools": [

      ],
      "BackupTools": [

      ]
    },
    "Services": [
      {
        "Code": "GIWS",
        "Name": "Grease Injection WHE Service",
        "Description": "",
        "GroupInfos": "",
        "ClassificationType": 4,
        "LegacySystemMapping": [
          {
            "LegacyId": "EE61B186-CE57-46A8-B280-FE913CC8FF33",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Grease Injection WHE Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "ODM"
          },
          {
            "LegacyId": "2e4b1aea-3d91-43b6-9c32-a165a546ed39",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Grease Injection WHE Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "OSCompliance"
          }
        ],
        "Source": "A",
        "Comments": "",
        "Id": "9c405cc1-5231-4baf-864f-7974bb4fbe07"
      },
      {
        "Code": "SCNNGWS",
        "Name": "Slick Cable Non-Grease Injection WHE Service",
        "Description": "",
        "GroupInfos": "",
        "ClassificationType": 4,
        "LegacySystemMapping": [
          {
            "LegacyId": "7B41D3DD-A6A7-47AF-81CD-5D8C248183B5",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Slick Cable Non-Grease Injection WHE Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "ODM"
          },
          {
            "LegacyId": "399e61ed-353a-404f-aad3-1e84c46cb273",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Slick Cable Non-Grease Injection WHE Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "OSCompliance"
          }
        ],
        "Source": "A",
        "Comments": "",
        "Id": "0a4848d3-7d93-4721-a556-2ecf1b0a7f43"
      },
      {
        "Code": "TPWS",
        "Name": "Third Party WHE Service",
        "Description": "",
        "GroupInfos": "",
        "ClassificationType": 4,
        "LegacySystemMapping": [
          {
            "LegacyId": "CAF5754A-3F90-40C6-82AC-0A4F484A4E74",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Third Party WHE Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "ODM"
          },
          {
            "LegacyId": "50ff1668-0b3b-489c-a7ad-794e327028e5",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Third Party WHE Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "OSCompliance"
          }
        ],
        "Source": "A",
        "Comments": "",
        "Id": "ee923f9e-210f-4c36-8fc4-f1e9521d0cbe"
      },
      {
        "Code": "WLPPS",
        "Name": "Wireline Low Pressure Packoff Service",
        "Description": "",
        "GroupInfos": "",
        "ClassificationType": 4,
        "LegacySystemMapping": [
          {
            "LegacyId": "CB79CDE1-2271-418D-9E67-D4B07E94AC61",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Wireline Low Pressure Packoff Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "ODM"
          },
          {
            "LegacyId": "514650dd-5b71-4889-b991-0d77dd355666",
            "LegacySystemMappedProperty": "Wireline Low Pressure Packoff Service",
            "LegacySystemName": "OSCompliance"
          }
        ],
        "Source": "A",
        "Comments": "",
        "Id": "2216c1c0-41ba-40aa-90c2-1096e8191d2c"
      }
    ],
    "Tools": ""
  },
  "ComboType": 2,
  "HashCode": "",
  "SequenceNumber": "",
  "ConveyanceInfo": "",
  "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "CreatedBy": "",
  "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "LastModifiedBy": "",
  "Id": "446d43e1-6476-4408-b850-e5f233933ba9"
  ```

  }
  ],
  "CreatedDate": "2019-09-09T13:12:14.94",
  "CreatedBy": "VHiremath",
  "LastModifiedDate": "2020-02-27T07:40:08.071",
  "LastModifiedBy": "VPanath",
  "Id": "5d764fae3d6a351088a1c9d3"
  }

**Code:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
  if(result){return result;} 
  else {return [];}
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://temp-dev-workspace/json_temp/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);

SELECT job_id,
combo_id,
tool_code
from temp.dbm_eqp_data,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Combos[*].ComboId')) combo_id,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Combos[*].Demands.DownHoleTools.PrimaryTools[*].ToolCode')) tool_code
;
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: expected output]

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant - Request your expertise help here, i have tried all possible solutions suggested earlier , but I am missing something here. request your help

Comment: 1. you can only reach SO members who already part of the post - in this case they will get your "message" in their inbox. Otherwise it is ignored. 2. you need to narrow down your issue to something that is easy to consume / work with. Try to simplify (make shorter) you example and explain what is expected result is

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Thanks so much , you are always a saviour...I have given the sample input data and expected output and code i have currently to deal this. Request your help.

Comment: i will check it shortly :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Thanks a lot again

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - I have extended this solution for another set and it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  var result = jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
  if(result){return result;} 
  else {return [];}
'''
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://temp-dev-workspace/json_temp/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
SELECT 
  job_id,
  combo_id,
  tool_code
FROM `temp.dbm_eqp_data`,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Combos[*].ComboId')) combo_id
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Combos[?(@.ComboId=="' || combo_id || '")].Demands.DownHoleTools.PrimaryTools[*].ToolCode')) tool_code
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - output is

```
Row job_id  combo_id    tool_code    
1   1       9146        19139    
2   1       9146        7030     
3   1       9146        3707     
4   1       9146        3707     
5   1       5970        null     
6   1       5971        null     
7   1       26793       null
```

Comment: Thanks so much , I have further extended it to read other attributes for each tool codes and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I tried to further extend it to read all attributes and it just executes and never returns any result.I doing something wrong here. CODE: UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Equipments.Combos[*].ComboId')) combo_id
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Combos[?(@.ComboId=="' || combo_id || '")].Demands.DownHoleTools.PrimaryTools[*].ToolCode')) tool_code
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Combos[?(@.ComboId=="' || combo_id || '")].Demands.DownHoleTools.PrimaryTools[?(@.ToolCode=="' || tool_code || '")].ToolDescription')) tool_description

Comment: comments are not good media for rich info - in any case - your current question is fully answered - if you have new question - please post new one and I (we) will be happy to help. this is how it works here at SO :o)

Comment: Sure, I will post a new question. Thanks a lot again

Comment: just a sec  - i feel you have just typos - give me a sec

Comment: i think you have extra "Equipments" in first UNNEST - i just run it and it works - if still not  - in this case - post new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210618/discussion-between-nanda-and-mikhail-berlyant).